# Callback service gets status 302 for a servlet, direct browser access status 200

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, redirect, https, http-status-code-302

I created a servlet on Google Appengine. I I call it in a browser I can see it and the nework console of Chrome and Firefox show me one request with status code 200.

Now I am trying to integrate a webservice thats sends a callback response to this URL. And this service tells me, it receives a "302 Found" status code and therefore does not work.

Could this be related to some SSL redirect? I tried with https and http. Both do return a 200 in the browser, 302 for the web service.
Is there a better tool to debug this than the browser? Is the browser maybe hiding the redirect?

Or whats the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

The browser console [F12] may hide the request if you watch the requets of the current page only. In Chrome Developer tools -> Network you can clear the list, then type the initial url in browser address bar.

Or: use a command line tool, to show the header i.e.

```
curl -I [url]
wget -O /dev/null -S [url]
```

The redirect is in the line "Location: ..." of the shown response header.